# PySpark: how to get the maximum absolute value of a column in a data frame?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have

```
+----+---+
|  v1| v2|
+----+---+
|-1.0|  0|
| 0.0|  1|
| 1.0|  2|
|-2.0|  3|
+----+---+
```

I want get the max absolute value of column `v1`, which is `2.0`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `agg` with `max` and `abs` from `pyspark.sql.functions`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.agg(F.max(F.abs(df.v1))).first()[0]
# 2
```